# r shiny download filtrered datatables (DT)

Tags: r, download, datatables, shiny, dt

i'm trying to do a `shiny` app to download a filtred `Datatable` :

- filtered with the `search`
- filtred by deleting line with the `delete button`

(the download part is working as intended)

the problem : when i first filter with the searsh area from Datatable if i delete a line with the button it reset the first filter

my reproductible exemple : **edit working solution**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Info boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('data')),
    fluidRow(p(class = 'text-center', downloadButton('x3', 'Download Filtered Data')))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
      Value1 = 1:10,
      Value2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = 1:10
   ))

   output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
   df$data, server =  TRUE, filter = 'top', escape = FALSE, selection = 'none')

   # download the filtered data
    output$x3 = downloadHandler('emergence filtré.csv', content = function(file) {
        s = input$data_rows_all
        write.table(df$data[s,], file  ,sep=";",row.names = F)
     })    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because the search filter is done on the client's side (within the web browser) and it does not really change the underlying data frame. A possible alternative is to add a filter to the table and use that as search function, and also set server side processing. This won't do global searching in one box though.

```
output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
  df$data, server = TRUE, filter = 'top', escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
)
```

Comment: it's working i edited the code (andremoved the delete button)