# R + Shiny + DT : download filtered data

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

I am trying to do something along the lines of

[r shiny download filtrered datatables (DT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836473/r-shiny-download-filtrered-datatables-dt)

i.e. given a table in Shiny, search for some keywords and download the filtered dataset.
I need to be able to download the data filtered both with a button and by selecting some keywords. In real life the dataset I am dealing with is much more complex and I cannot foresee all the possible filters beforehand.
The example I mention uses "reactiveValues", whereas I rely on "reactive" and for some reasons I have been banging my head against the wall.

In the reprex below, if I select "fish" as animal type and I search for "high", I end up with 3 records, but the dataset I download has in any case 10 records.
How do I download the filtered dataset?

Thanks!

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(readr)

### small helper function

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
      12, h1(paste0(title)),      
      hr(), DTOutput(id)
  ))
}



df <- tibble(animal=rep(c("dog", "fish", "cat"), 10),
             code=rep(LETTERS[1:10],3),
             price_tag=c(rep("high",10),rep("average",10), rep("low",10))

             )


ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
             pickerInput("mypet","Select animal type", choices=c("cat", "dog", "fish"),
                        selected="fish",
                        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                       `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = T),

             downloadButton("downloadData", "Download your selection")

             )
         ,
         mainPanel(
dt_output("Raw Data Selection","table")
             
    )
     )
)



server <- function(input, output) {

    df_filter <- reactive({

        df %>%
            filter(animal %in% input$mypet)
        
    })

    output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df_filter())})

        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("filtered_data.csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write_csv(df_filter(), file)

    }
  )

    
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7081
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with a **datatables** button, not with a download handler:

```
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      df_filter(),
      extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip",
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "csv",
            exportOptions = list(
              modifier = list(
                search = "applied"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since DT is an output, you can create your own searchbox input:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)


dt_output <- function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0(title)),
    hr(), DTOutput(id)
  ))
}



df <- tibble(
  animal = rep(c("dog", "fish", "cat"), 10),
  code = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 3),
  price_tag = c(rep("high", 10), rep("average", 10), rep("low", 10))
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("mypet", "Select animal type",
        choices = c("cat", "dog", "fish"),
        selected = "fish",
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
        ), multiple = T
      ),
      textInput("search", label = "Search table", placeholder = "search"),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download your selection")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dt_output("Raw Data Selection", "table")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  df_filter <- reactive({
    selected_rows <-
      df %>%
      unite(all, everything()) %>%
      mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
      filter(all %>% str_detect(input$search)) %>%
      pull(id)


    df %>%
      filter(animal %in% input$mypet & row_number() %in% selected_rows)
  })

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(df_filter(), options = list(dom = "t"), filter = list())
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("filtered_data.csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write_csv(df_filter(), file)
    }
  )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I do *not* want. In real life and with many columns I do not want to create dozens of searchboxes. I really want to be able to do as described in my post.

Comment: My answer is independent of the columns. All columns are searched at the same time using my search box.

Comment: I meant to say that in my app I do not know before hand the list of the possible keywords to look for (it would be hundreds to say the least).

Comment: Do you need keyword competition in the search box?

Comment: *keyword auto-completion

Comment: I have not thought about it, but it could be handy!

Comment: Just replace the seach box with a [`selectizeInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html)